# Fedora 35 (Silverblue) installer, and then system, boots only into text-mode

Tags: linux, boot, installation, fedora, wayland

I'm attempting to install Fedora 35 Silverblue for the first time. I've partitioned my drive using Windows 11, leaving 150GB of free-space; then I booted to the Silverblue USB-stick I burned.

The installation didn't boot into the documentation-predicted GUI — instead, it was textmode only (saying "X or windows manager startup failed, falling back to text mode.")

After completing text-mode installation into the free-space, I reboot into Fedora Silverblue, and end up at a text-mode prompt:

```
Fedora Linux 35.1.2 (Silverblue)
Kernel 5.14.10...

fedora login:
```

1. How do I figure out why I can't seem to get a GUI? Is there a relevant log I can check?
2. If the installer ran in text-mode, can I fix this and still enable graphics in the resulting installation — or do I need to focus on getting the *installer* to run in graphical-mode?

Hardware:

```
MSI Creator Z17
17" QHD+ (2560*1600), 165Hz DCI-P3 (I wonder if the hiDPI display is the culprit somehow?)
Intel Core i9-12900H
NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3080 TI
```

Comment: `journalctl` would be the relevant log

Answer (score 0):

> NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3080 TI

I do not believe that these cards are supported by the "nouveau" open source driver yet. See [Nouveau: Feature Matrix](https://nouveau.freedesktop.org/FeatureMatrix.html) — this is an NV170 card, and as of the time I'm writing this, that column is entirely bright red and marked `TODO`.

You can install in text-only mode and enable graphics from there — in fact, that's what you'll have to do. Follow the instructions at https://rpmfusion.org/Howto/NVIDIA#Silverblue, and then

```
systemctl set-default graphical.target
```

to have the system boot into graphical mode. (`systemctl isolate graphical.target` to make it happen immediately.)